# Making a GET request using AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, rest, controller, cross-domain, jsonp

I am new to angularJS and am trying to figure out how to make a GET request to an external server. This is what their documentation
lists as an example request:

**Example Request**

> curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json' -H 'Authorization:
>   OAuth [access_token]' \
>   -X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken

I am trying to call a service from my controller to make this RESTful call and this is what I have so far:

**Controller**:

```
angular.module('myAppController')
.controller('LandingCtrl', ['$scope', 'twitchService', 
  function($scope, twitchService) {
    // assume access token is a variable that's been set by this point
    twitchService.getUserRootInfo({accesstoken : access_token})
    .success(function(rootInfoResponse,status,headers){
        // do stuff with rootInfoResponse
    });
  }]);
```

**Service**:

```
var myAppServices = angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
myAppServices.factory('twitchService', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken', {}, {
          getUserRootInfo: {
            // not sure what to put here...
            // how do I use the variable I (hopefully) passed in here "accesstoken" from my controller?
          }
    });
  }
]);
```

First of all, is my code right so far? Second of all, the API documentation states the following:

> All API methods support JSON-P by providing a callback parameter with
>   the request.

I've already come accross issues in the past with cross-domain requests and am aware of the same origin policy so
does that mean I have to use a JSONP request in my service? If so, can someone demonstrate how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to pass up an argument in your call you'll need to use a POST like this

```
  getUserRootInfo: function(token) {

       return $http.post(URL, {'token':token}).
        success(function(data) {
            // The call succeeded.
        }).error(function(data) {
           // the call failed
        });

  }
```

Or some variation of this. And you can call it like this:

```
   var promise = twitchService.getUserRootInfo(mytoken); 
   promise.then(function(response) {
     // check response.data if you have values coming back that need to be checked
   });
```

Of course you can switch things up with what is returned, etc. to match your style, but this is the basic gist of how it works.